# Change HTML content of a "tbody" in a table with AJAX call

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function in PHP that returns a JSON like this:

```
{"tableRow":[ {"tipo":"Noche"},{"patente":"XZ7410"},{"nombre":"Marcela Bien"},
              {"revisado":0},{"id_registro":"10"},
              {"tipo":"Vespertino"},{"patente":"EW3651"},{"nombre":"Alexis Diaz"},
              {"revisado":1},{"id_registro":"9"} ]
}
```

Also have this table with some HTML content created by default:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover table-bordered pull-left" id="data-table">    
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Turno</th>
      <th>ID Máquina</th>
      <th>Operador</th>
      <th>Semáforo</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data-update">
    <tr>
      <td>Noche</td>
      <td>XZ7410</td>
      <td>Marcela Bien</td>
      <td><img src="/monitor/web/images/bullet_red.png" /></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-mini" href="/monitor/web/frontend_dev.php/ver-detalles/10">Ver detalles</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vespertino</td>
      <td>EW3651</td>
      <td>Alexis Diaz</td>
      <td><img src="/monitor/web/images/bullet_orange.png" /></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-mini" href="/monitor/web/frontend_dev.php/ver-detalles/9">Ver detalles</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to update #data-update HTML content with the one generated from PHP and give to jQuery as JSON so I wrote this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '<?php echo url_for('dashboard/BuildAjax') ?>',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var newRows;
            for (var i in data.tableRow) {
                newRows += "<tr><td>" + data.tableRow[i].tipo + "</td>"
                newRows += "<td>" + data.tableRow[i].patente + "</td>"
                newRows += "<td>" + data.tableRow[i].nombre + "</td>"
                newRows += "<td>" + data.tableRow[i].revisado + "</td>"
                newRows += "<td>" + data.tableRow[i].id_registro + "</td></tr>"
            }
            $("#data-update").html(newRows);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('<?php echo __('Error al cargar los datos') ?>');
        }
    });
    }, 10000);
});
```

The HTML content is changed but not in the right way. What this mean? I'm getting a table like this as a result:

```
Turno      ID Maquina  Operador        Semaforo    
Noche      undefined   undefined       undefined
undefined  XZ7410      undefined       undefined 
undefined  undefined   Marcela Bien    undefined 
undefined  undefined   undefined       1
undefined  undefined   undefined       undefined      10

Vespertino undefined   undefined       undefined
undefined  EW3651      undefined       undefined 
undefined  undefined   Alexis Diaz     undefined 
undefined  undefined   undefined       0
undefined  undefined   undefined       undefined      12
```

When should get something like:

```
Turno      ID Maquina  Operador        Semaforo 
Noche      XZ7410      Marcela Bien    1           10
Vespertino EW3651      Alexis Diaz     0           12
```

What is wrong? I can't found where I made the mistake, any help or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bobbe suggests, you could have your PHP function output json that is easier to consume. But if you are stuck with the present output you could parse it like this:

```
...
success: function(data) {
  var n, newRows = '', tds = data.tableRow;
  $.each(tds, function(i, td) {
     n = i % 4;
     switch(n) {
       case 0:
         newRows += '<tr><td>' + td.tipo + '</td>';
         break;
       case 1:
         newRows += '<td>' + td.patente + '</td>';
         break;
       case 2:
         newRows += '<td>' + td.nombre + '</td>';
         break;
       case 3:
         newRows += '<td>' + td.id_registro + '</td></tr>';
         break;
      }
    });
    $("#data-update").html(newRows);
    ...
```

Comment: yes I'm a bit stucked with the JSON tryng to get the right version from PHP, I test your code and it works with a few hacks ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your tableRow data are incorrect in that it contains only one row of 10 elements.

Shouldn't it be:

```
{"tableRow":[ 
    {
        "tipo":"Noche",
        "patente":"XZ7410",
        "nombre":"Marcela Bien",
        "revisado":0,
        "id_registro":"10"
    },
    {
        "tipo":"Vespertino",
        ...
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats because you have bad JSON. 
You need some structure like this

```
{"tableRow":[ {"tipo":"Noche",
               "patente":"XZ7410",
               "nombre":"Marcela Bien",
               "revisado":0,
               "id_registro":"10"},
              {"tipo":"Vespertino"
              ,"patente":"EW3651",
               "nombre":"Alexis Diaz",
               "revisado":1,
               "id_registro":"9"} 
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that I see.

**Problem 1:**

Your JSON structure does not match how you are trying to use it. For your code to work in the manner you expect, your JSON should be structured ike this:

```
{
    "tableRow": [{
        "tipo": "Noche",
        "patente": "XZ7410",
        "nombre": "Marcela Bien",
        "revisado": 0,
        "id_registro": "10"
    }, {
        "tipo": "Vespertino",
        "patente": "EW3651",
        "nombre": "Alexis Diaz",
        "revisado": 1,
        "id_registro": "9",
    }]
}
```

The best solution wuld be to correct the structure of the JSON so that each row is an object, but if you're intent on correcting this given your existing JSON structure, you'd need to do something like:

```
var newRows = '',
    row = 0,
    i = 0;
for (row = 0; row < data.tableRow; row += 1) {
    if (row % 5 === 0) {
        newRows += "<tr>";
        for (i in data.tableRow[row]) {
            newRows += "<td>" + data.tableRow[row][i] + "</td>"
        }
        newRows += "</tr>";
    }
}
$("#data-update").html(newRows);
```

**Problem 2**

Not nearly as bad as Problem 1, but you're not providing an initial value for `newRows` so appending strings to it is going to net you a result of:

```
undefined<tr><td>... //rest of string
```

The solution is to define `newRows` as an empty string:

```
var newRows = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is making an iteration for each item in your JSON like it should be doing (the reason why only one item is actually defined for each row, the item it "thinks" is the whole row of data)....format your JSON so that it has separate items for each row of data.